# How to remove the .0 in a integter in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove the `.0` when I am calculating on these times.

```
current_time = datetime.timedelta(hours = 22, minutes = 30)
program_end = datetime.timedelta(hours = 23, minutes = 40)
program_duration = program_end - current_time
program_widths = int(program_duration.seconds / 60)
program_widths = program_widths * 11.4
```

Output:

```
794.0
```

Results

```
>>>> 794
```

Can you please help me how I can remove the `.0` as I am using a integer?

Comment: It's because it is a `float`. If you want an integer, you need to convert it - `int(variable)`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here though.

Comment: I am trying to remove the `.0` from the int `794.0` to make it as `794` as the output. Can you show me how I can achieve it?

Comment: [Learn about built-in types...](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) You're handling a float - that is clearly not an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `int` function to cast your `float` number to `int`:

```
int(794.0) # 794
```

and in your program try this `program_widths = int(program_widths)` if you want your variable become `int` if you want just print it as `int` just cast to int for print -> `print int(program_widths)`

Comment: @TimCullen Pretty much. You might want those statements on separate lines though :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because it is a float. If you want an integer, you need to convert it:

```
int(variable)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your float to an int, your option of:

```
int(program_widths)
print program_widths
```

Doesn't work because you cast it yet don't keep the result, you should just change the printing to:

```
print int(program_widths)
```